# Excel VBA Code Doesn't Work Properly in Group

Tags: excel

I am new to VBA coding just like most of the people who ask questions like this one here. :)
I wrote a code which runs without any error but for some reason the second part is not executed if it is run in a group. Surprisingly, it does its job if I run the second part of the code on its own. 
Can someone give me a bit of guidance what is causing this problem?

```
Sub Macro1()
 Endrow1 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer

For i = 3 To Endrow1
     With Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "No" Then Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
        If Left(.Value, 3) = "Yes" Then
        Rows(i).Font.Bold = True
            a = Cells(i, 3).Value
            For j = 0 To 30
                Cells(j + i, 12).Value = a
            Next j

        End If
    End With
Next i

'------------------------------------------------------------------- Second Part:
For j = 3 To 300
     With Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 7)
     If Cells(j, 7).Value >= a And Cells(j, 7) <= Cells(1, 11) Then

          If Cells(j, 12) = Cells(j, 12) Then
          On Error Resume Next
          For k = 0 To 30
            If Cells(j + k, 12) = Cells(j, 12) Then Cells(j + k, 12).Interior.Color = 255
            If Cells(j - k, 12) = Cells(j, 12) Then Cells(j - k, 12).Interior.Color = 255

          Next k
            End If
      End If
    End With
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "in a group" and "on it's own"?

Comment: By "group", I mean the first and second part of the code is run as one macro.
If I copy and paste the second part of the code onto a different sheet and run it, It is doing its job perfectly.

Comment: Could you please provide some dummy data for us to try to get your scenario?

Comment: When you debug this, do you get past this condition "If Cells(j, 7).Value >= a And Cells(j, 7) <= Cells(1, 11) Then"? Also, what is the 'on error resume next' hiding? Lastly, I don't think your 'With' structure is doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

> When you debug this, do you get past this condition "If Cells(j, 7).Value >= a And Cells(j, 7) <= Cells(1, 11) Then"? Also, what is the 'on error resume next' hiding? Lastly, I don't think your 'With' structure is doing anything.

Thank you for your answer Martin. The problem was caused by my first if statement in the second part.
This is the correct version:

```
For j = 3 To 300
 With Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 7)
 If Cells(j, 7).Value <= Cells(1, 11) Then

      If Cells(j, 12) = Cells(j, 12) Then
      On Error Resume Next
      For k = 0 To 30
        If Cells(j + k, 12) = Cells(j, 12) Then Cells(j + k, 12).Interior.Color = 255
        If Cells(j - k, 12) = Cells(j, 12) Then Cells(j - k, 12).Interior.Color = 255

      Next k
        End If
  End If
End With
```

Next j

I will get rid off the with statement later. :)